# how to group these tags based on the posts that they were extracted from?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I'm extracting hashtags that were part of user posts.

For example, if a post is "Hi stackoverflow #new #hello"
I'm extracting "new" and "hello" into my hashtags database

Here's the table info

```
create_table "hashtags", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "hashtags"
    t.integer  "post_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",   :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   :null => false
  end
```

I'm saving the post_id that the hashtag was associated with but I'm having trouble grouping them together based on whether they were from the same post or not.

Here's what I have so far in view

```
<ul> 
<% @hashtags.each do |h| %>
<li><%= link_to "#"+h.hashtags, "#" %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

This shows separately as

- #new
- #hello

I'd like to show in a single line as they're from the same post_id like

- #new - #hello

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I get what you want but you can use the following:

```
<ul> 
  <li><%= link_to @hashtags.map{|h| "##{h.hashtags}"}.join(' - '), "#" %></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: does this map based on the post_id? what if I want to join hashtags that are from the same post_id, but separate to a new line below if from another post_id?

Comment: Based on your implementation, you should then have an array of arrays of hashtags and add a loop for the first array (for each different post) right after the <ul> tag.

Comment: can you please point me in the right direction? I'm not exactly sure how to have an array of arrays with a loop. Any help here would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You should do something like: 
`<ul>
  <% @posts.each do |post| 
    <li>
      <%= link_to post.hashtags.map{|h| "##{h.hashtags}"}.join(' - '), "#" %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>`

Comment: I did this inside my controller index: `@posts = Hashtag.find(:all, :order => 'created_at DESC')`, then used your code but I'm getting this error: `undefined method 'map' for "xxxxxx":String`. Do you know anything about this?

Comment: Posts should be all your posts, not your hashtags. Should be something like: @posts = Post.all. So if in your post model you have the has_many hashtags, you should be cool.